# Oracle chain results in "job slave process was terminated" for concurrent job execution

Tags: sql, oracle, scheduler

Currently I have an Oracle chain defined with the following steps:

```
1) TRUE  
     START first,second,third  
2)  first COMPLETED AND second COMPLETED AND third COMPLETED  
    START A,B,C  
3)  A COMPLETED AND B COMPLETED AND C COMPLETED  
    END
```

first.sql:

```
create materialized view first_View  
nologging  
never refresh  
as  
select * from first
```

second.sql:

```
create materialized view second_View  
nologging  
never refresh  
as  
select * from second
```

third.sql:

```
create materialized view third_View  
nologging  
never refresh  
as  
select * from third
```

The error I receive is this:

```
CHAIN_LOG_ID="4321", STEP_NAME="SECOND" REASON="Job slave process was terminated"
```

The box has 16 CPUs, so any insight as to why this is happening would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [LogMiner](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/logminer.htm) to Analyze Redo Log Files. Obviously, the session has been killed.

Comment: Why was the session killed, but nothing in the logs stated killed?

Comment: Check all Dump (UDUMP, BDUMP, CDUMP, ADUMP), Diag Trace and Diag Alert locations - something should be there.